# Why do most Togruta wear headdresses?

Tags: star-wars

I understand the Akul tooth headdress is a sign of bravery and skill, but many Togruta sport other headwear (including Ashoka in later canon material). Is there a reason that most of them seem to wear a headband where their montrals meet their skull, or is it purely ornate?

Comment: It's called fashion, dahling...

Comment: @valorum that’s what I’m asking. Is there any canonical evidence that it is just fashion?

Comment: Hmm...  How many Togruta do we see deliberately *not* wearing a headband / covering of some sort?  3-year-old Ahsoka when Plo Koon first meets her, but any other / older ones?

Comment: You're telling me that's not a part of them?!?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is actually answered with more detail on Wookieepedia.

The main headdresses Togruta wear are the akul teeth headdresses. We see Ahsoka Tano and Shaak Ti with these. These headdresses are gained from a Togruta coming-of-age tradition, hunting down akul. An akul is a predator on Shili that had incredibly negative effects on its environment. In a coming-of-age ceremony, a Togruta is sent to hunt one down alone, and if successful, they are to wear the teeth of the dead akul to signify their success. We can assume Ahsoka completed her trials sometime before she turned 14 and became Anakin's padawan.

The beads that we saw Shaak Ti wear? Well, that's most likely another Togruta tradition that was unspecified. It could just be fashion, though.

In Star Wars Rebels, we see a 31-32 year old Ahsoka Tano with a sort of tiara-like headdress. It's never specified where she got it or why she wears it, but we can assume she just decided to discard her akul tooth headdress after the Jedi Purge and found those. Because we never see her without any headdresses, we can also assume that Togruta are required to wear something between their montrals and foreheads. This is similar to the Twi-lek requirement that females cover at least part of their lekku.